# My Icon Theme is Not Applying to All Applications On Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: gnome, icons, themes, gnome-tweak-tool, numix

I'm trying to apply icon themes in my Ubuntu 18.04 setup, and for some reason, certain icons won't have icons applied to them, even though I know they're icons designed for said applications. When I was on Ubuntu 16.04, I used the numix circle icon theme, and there was a circle icon for Discord and Gimp. Now, with the same icon theme, those icons won't be applied. I tried the papirus icon theme as well, with the same result. How can I fix this? I applied the icon theme using the gnome-tweak tool.

Answer (score 1):

If you installed the applications via snap, there is a problem with snaps accessing some global settings like themes. See https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/use-the-system-gtk-theme/496/3 for a more technical description.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the app icon yourself though, and pick the Numix one. You have to start Files/Nautilus as Super User with

```
sudo nautilus
```

find the app, right click, properties, then click on the app icon, look for the Numix one and apply.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following commands in ubuntu terminal:

`sudo apt update --fix-missing && sudo apt upgrade`

The above command for update and fix the incomplete updates and upgrades

`sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop`

The above command reinstall ubuntu desktop icons and theme

`sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-shell-extensions`

`sudo apt-get install --reinstall whatevertheme`

The above two commands are for reinstalling gnome shell extensions and troubled themes.

This may fix all the issues of missing icons or themes.

If the problem still persists please write here will give few more instructions...

Answer (score 0):

Iam using ubuntu 20.04lts

Icon themes are generally under `/usr/share/icons/${THEME_NAME}`. For the purposes of examples in this guide, I'll be using the Numix-Circle icons.
Now open terminal and type `sudo nautilus` this will open file manager with super user now follow these steps.

Snaps are installed under /var/lib/snapd. Their corresponding desktop files are under `/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications`. Opening any desktop file with text editor we can see a line that begins with Icon=.

Go into your theme directory that you found earlier, and find the corresponding icon in there. For Numix, these are under `/usr/share/icons/Numix-Circle/48/apps`. Replace the path in the .desktop file with your desire icon. Restart your computer.

Now no longer you will see ugly square icons in your dock.

Note: If you update your snap application you have to repeat this process again.

Comment: Replacing icons by hand is not a solution for theming, is a way of manually changing icons. Whenever you change your icons theme then you will have to change all icons for snaps and desktop applications too.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using v22.04 but this sure applies to gnome in general and not to a very Ubuntu specific version.
I generally use tweaks to change themes on gnome but some icons don't change no matter what.

### For those Icons that doesn't change after switching the theme:

There are several folders where you will find desktop entries (icons on dock or apps menu):

**local** `~/.local/share/applications` (overrides the other folders)
**gnome** `/usr/share/icons/${THEME_NAME}`
**flatpak** `/var/lib/flatpak/...`
**snapd** `/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications`

The problem with these `.desktop` files is that the config value is set to a specific picture file and not to a name.

If you want change your icons by switching themes on tweaks, then you will have to manually edit `.desktop` file for each app that was not affected by the new chosen theme .

You will have to replace it with the name of the app to make this icon change when changing your theme.

*example:*
file: /var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/libreoffice-calc.desktop
`Icon=/snap/libreoffice/300/usr/share/icons/hicolor/256x256/apps/libreoffice7.6-calc.png`
replace it with
`Icon=libreoffice-calc`

On your theme folder, you will have to put a file with that name: `libreoffice-calc`. The extension of the file and the folder where to put it will depend on the theme configuration.

This will brake themes that doesn't have icons for some apps. Every theme has an inherit option:
*example:*
`Inherits=breeze-dark,Adwaita,hicolor`

Just because I have not found a good default icons options on Ubuntu, I decide to create a new theme with all the missing icons of the apps I installed. Then I made those broken themes to inherit from the new theme. Lot of work for something that I thing should be solved by default on Ubuntu or apps installers.
This way I only change the inheritance (one line) on themes like Yaru or any other theme with broken icons.

### List of apps with broken icons on my computer:

- Discord
- All LibreOffice apps
- All IDEs from Jetbrains
- Ms Teams
- Blender (snap)
- Vlc (snap)
- Obsidian
- Logseq
- etc... (a lot more)

*Theme used as example* [Candy Icons:](https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1305251)

Before:
[image]

After:
[image: Candy icons example]